# Acrescentar itens vazios no final de array

Tags: php, json, array, loop

Olá pessoal preciso fazer o seguinte e não estou dando conta.
Tenho que criar uma array para gerar uma saida json com 50 itens por exemplo, mas se quando buscar no banco tiver somente 30 ele completar os 50 itens com valores vazios. Com os mesmo keys, mas sem valores.

```
while ($rowx = $stmtx->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                    extract($rowx);

                    $emp_itemx=array(
                        "idhis" => $idhis,      
                        "id_user_cartao" => $id_user_cartao,
                        "ponto" => $ponto,
                        "id_user" => $id_user,
                        "qtde_pontos" => $qtde_pontos,
                        "iduserpromo" => $iduserpromo
                    );

                }

                echo json_encode($emp_itemx);
```

Comment: por que essa linha  do PDO não tá assim: $rowx = $stmtx->fetchAll(); já que virão varios resgistros do bd o fetchAll é mais indicado

Comment: dessa forma não seria também necessário chamar a função extract já que o resultado já viria assim $emp_itemx= array([0] =>array(
                    "idhis" => "xxxx",      
                    "id_user_cartao" => "xxxx",
                    "ponto" => "xxxx",
                    "id_user" => "xxxx",
                    "qtde_pontos" => "xxxx",
                    "iduserpromo" => "xxxx")
                );

Comment: Marcos, valeu a dica, mas o meu problema é como descrevi acima, a questão dos dados do banco não estou tendo problemas. Preciso mesmo é completar os dados em branco no array!!

Comment: o array que você representou está errado, é mais fácil iterar sobre o retorno usando um foreach ao final ao invés do while

Comment: retorno  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 'xxx',
            [id_user_cartao] => 'xxx',
            [ponto] => 'xxx',
            [id_user] => 'xxx',
            [qtde_pontos] => 'xxx',
            [iduserpromo] => 'xxx'
        )

Comment: Tudo bem, mas como eu poderia completar o resultado que preciso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nesse caso estou supondo que só existe um registro retornado do BD:

```
$emp_itemx=array(array(
                "idhis" => 'xxx',      
                "id_user_cartao" => 'xxxx',
                "ponto" => 'xxx',
                "id_user" => 'xxx',
                "qtde_pontos" => 'xxx',
                "iduserpromo" => 'xxxx'
            ));


for($i = count($emp_itemx);$i < 50;$i++){
$emp_itemx[$i] = array(
"idhis" => '',      
"id_user_cartao" => '',
"ponto" => '',
"id_user" => '',
"qtde_pontos" => '',
    "iduserpromo" => '');
```

}

desssa forma ele acrescentará tantos quantos forem necessário até atingir os 50 registros

Comment: Vou testar e já aviso!!  Valeu

Comment: Marcos, ela está repetindo a quantidade que falta pra inteirar 50 depois de cada item que vem do banco e não só final de todos!! se tenho 20 linhas no banco ele coloca mais 30 depois de cada um, ficando com 600 linhas no array.

Comment: é essa a questão, você deve ter inserido o for dentro do while

Comment: Realmente, vacilo. Está completando o restando certo fora do while, mas está retornando somente 1 item que vem do banco!!

Comment: por isso te falei sobre substituir o fetch() pelo fetchAll();

Comment: assim: $emp_itemx = $stmtx->fetchAll(); você economiza um while() e um extract(); e não vai precisar nem mesmo iterar esse array. o json_encode já entende

Comment: Quem sabe sabe. Valeu Marcão. Tava sofrendo aqui, agora que peguei seu raciocínio, não precisava de nada daquilo mesmo, é não estou acostumado com PDO, eu sempre uso msqli.

Comment: Veja como fiz:
`
$card_arrx=array();
    $emp_itemx = $stmtx->fetchAll();

    for($i = count($emp_itemx);$i < 15;$i++){
    //echo "cont: ".$i;
    $emp_itemx[$i] = array(
    "idhis" => '',      
    "id_user_cartao" => '',
    "ponto" => '',
    "id_user" => '',
    "qtde_pontos" => '',
     "iduserpromo" => '');
    }`

Comment: insere na pergunta as linhas de código que vem antes, não to entendendo essa linha $card_arrx=array();

Comment: Marcos, somente iniciei a variável do tipo array.

Comment: então funcionou?

Comment: Funcionou sim Marcos, graças às duas dicas. Obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

Preencha um array com um valor determinado através da função [`array_fill()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-fill.php) e combine dois ou mais arrays pela função [`array_merge()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php)

```
<?php
$array1 = []; 

//Define um elemento vazio para posterior preenchimento
$vazio = [
  "idhis" => null,      
  "id_user_cartao" => null,
  "ponto" => null,
  "id_user" => null,
  "qtde_pontos" => null,
  "iduserpromo" => null
];

//Simula um preenchimento de 30 itens de $array1
foreach(range(1,30) as $n){
   $array1[] = [
    "idhis" => -$n,      
    "id_user_cartao" => $n,
    "ponto" => $n * 10,
    "id_user" => $n * 100,
    "qtde_pontos" => $n * 1000,
    "iduserpromo" => $n * 10000
  ];
}

//Cria um array 20 elementos definidos como sendo vazios
$array2 = array_fill(0, 20, $vazio);

//Junta $array1 e $array2
$resultado = array_merge($array1 , $array2);

print_r($resultado);
```

Teste o código funcionando em https://repl.it/repls/RemarkableWatchfulDemand

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -1
            [id_user_cartao] => 1
            [ponto] => 10
            [id_user] => 100
            [qtde_pontos] => 1000
            [iduserpromo] => 10000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -2
            [id_user_cartao] => 2
            [ponto] => 20
            [id_user] => 200
            [qtde_pontos] => 2000
            [iduserpromo] => 20000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -3
            [id_user_cartao] => 3
            [ponto] => 30
            [id_user] => 300
            [qtde_pontos] => 3000
            [iduserpromo] => 30000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -4
            [id_user_cartao] => 4
            [ponto] => 40
            [id_user] => 400
            [qtde_pontos] => 4000
            [iduserpromo] => 40000
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -5
            [id_user_cartao] => 5
            [ponto] => 50
            [id_user] => 500
            [qtde_pontos] => 5000
            [iduserpromo] => 50000
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -6
            [id_user_cartao] => 6
            [ponto] => 60
            [id_user] => 600
            [qtde_pontos] => 6000
            [iduserpromo] => 60000
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -7
            [id_user_cartao] => 7
            [ponto] => 70
            [id_user] => 700
            [qtde_pontos] => 7000
            [iduserpromo] => 70000
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -8
            [id_user_cartao] => 8
            [ponto] => 80
            [id_user] => 800
            [qtde_pontos] => 8000
            [iduserpromo] => 80000
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -9
            [id_user_cartao] => 9
            [ponto] => 90
            [id_user] => 900
            [qtde_pontos] => 9000
            [iduserpromo] => 90000
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -10
            [id_user_cartao] => 10
            [ponto] => 100
            [id_user] => 1000
            [qtde_pontos] => 10000
            [iduserpromo] => 100000
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -11
            [id_user_cartao] => 11
            [ponto] => 110
            [id_user] => 1100
            [qtde_pontos] => 11000
            [iduserpromo] => 110000
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -12
            [id_user_cartao] => 12
            [ponto] => 120
            [id_user] => 1200
            [qtde_pontos] => 12000
            [iduserpromo] => 120000
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -13
            [id_user_cartao] => 13
            [ponto] => 130
            [id_user] => 1300
            [qtde_pontos] => 13000
            [iduserpromo] => 130000
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -14
            [id_user_cartao] => 14
            [ponto] => 140
            [id_user] => 1400
            [qtde_pontos] => 14000
            [iduserpromo] => 140000
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -15
            [id_user_cartao] => 15
            [ponto] => 150
            [id_user] => 1500
            [qtde_pontos] => 15000
            [iduserpromo] => 150000
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -16
            [id_user_cartao] => 16
            [ponto] => 160
            [id_user] => 1600
            [qtde_pontos] => 16000
            [iduserpromo] => 160000
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -17
            [id_user_cartao] => 17
            [ponto] => 170
            [id_user] => 1700
            [qtde_pontos] => 17000
            [iduserpromo] => 170000
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -18
            [id_user_cartao] => 18
            [ponto] => 180
            [id_user] => 1800
            [qtde_pontos] => 18000
            [iduserpromo] => 180000
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -19
            [id_user_cartao] => 19
            [ponto] => 190
            [id_user] => 1900
            [qtde_pontos] => 19000
            [iduserpromo] => 190000
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -20
            [id_user_cartao] => 20
            [ponto] => 200
            [id_user] => 2000
            [qtde_pontos] => 20000
            [iduserpromo] => 200000
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -21
            [id_user_cartao] => 21
            [ponto] => 210
            [id_user] => 2100
            [qtde_pontos] => 21000
            [iduserpromo] => 210000
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -22
            [id_user_cartao] => 22
            [ponto] => 220
            [id_user] => 2200
            [qtde_pontos] => 22000
            [iduserpromo] => 220000
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -23
            [id_user_cartao] => 23
            [ponto] => 230
            [id_user] => 2300
            [qtde_pontos] => 23000
            [iduserpromo] => 230000
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -24
            [id_user_cartao] => 24
            [ponto] => 240
            [id_user] => 2400
            [qtde_pontos] => 24000
            [iduserpromo] => 240000
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -25
            [id_user_cartao] => 25
            [ponto] => 250
            [id_user] => 2500
            [qtde_pontos] => 25000
            [iduserpromo] => 250000
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -26
            [id_user_cartao] => 26
            [ponto] => 260
            [id_user] => 2600
            [qtde_pontos] => 26000
            [iduserpromo] => 260000
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -27
            [id_user_cartao] => 27
            [ponto] => 270
            [id_user] => 2700
            [qtde_pontos] => 27000
            [iduserpromo] => 270000
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -28
            [id_user_cartao] => 28
            [ponto] => 280
            [id_user] => 2800
            [qtde_pontos] => 28000
            [iduserpromo] => 280000
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -29
            [id_user_cartao] => 29
            [ponto] => 290
            [id_user] => 2900
            [qtde_pontos] => 29000
            [iduserpromo] => 290000
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => -30
            [id_user_cartao] => 30
            [ponto] => 300
            [id_user] => 3000
            [qtde_pontos] => 30000
            [iduserpromo] => 300000
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [43] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [44] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [45] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [46] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [47] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [48] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

    [49] => Array
        (
            [idhis] => 
            [id_user_cartao] => 
            [ponto] => 
            [id_user] => 
            [qtde_pontos] => 
            [iduserpromo] => 
        )

)
```